# Problem of adding to an outlet collection

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am developing an iOS application and I have, in one of my controllers, an outlet collection of UIImageView.

Each imageView inside has a different tag. Only when I loop over the collection to get their tag, only the tag of the first element I added inside appears..

Here is the relevant part of the code :

```
@IBOutlet var imageLine1: [UIImageView]!

for image in tabImage {
   print(image.tab)
   switch image.tab {
      // Here I do some stuff
   }
}
```

And now the display in the Xcode terminal :

```
6
```

And the first image I added to this table has a tag of 6. So I conclude that I didn't manage to add the other images (which I do with a control drag on the outlet collection).
Does anyone have any idea what the problem is/ how to fix it?

Namely that I already had a similar collection, which contained all the images, which I deleted to replace it with the one above. They had the same name and the same elements inside, maybe that interfered with the correct functioning.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is your question?  ¿Cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: It sounds like an interesting topic.  It will be a lot better if you show some lines of code to make your point.

Comment: Please share some code or error messages or sample screenshots for better understanding.

Comment: Ok I'll do this in a few hours

Answer (score 0):

When you delete the old outlet collection you have to reconnect them to the new outlet collection within Interface-Builder.
Also make sure to delete the references to the old outlet connection within IB.

Comment: You mean, by doing a control drag from IB to add it to the new outlet connection in the code, if so that's what I did. And to remove the old outlet connection I simply clicked on 'x' in the Referencing Outlet Collection